# Discord.py create_text_channel overwrites dynamic options

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a slash command for people to setup a bot in their server. During setup, the bot creates a category and adds channels but I want to add overwrites to make these channels read only.

The slash command takes in one parameter, 'role', so the user that is setting up the bot can choose which server role will have access to use the bot.

My question is... Is there a way to make all the roles of each individual server come up as a choice so the person setting up can just choose instead of typing it in?

I know app_commands.choices can't really dynamically take in outside data but maybe because the data is coming from the Discord server it can somehow?

```py
    @bot.tree.command(name="setupBot", description="Enter role needed for 
                                                               access")
    async def setupBot(ctx, role: str,):

        await ctx.send("Setting up category and channels!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the object `discord.Role` to the parameter `role`. This would prompt for a role instead of text. From there, you can use `role` as `discord.Role` right away.

```
@bot.tree.command(name="setupBot", description="Enter role needed for access")
async def setupBot(ctx, role: discord.Role,):

    await ctx.send("Setting up category and channels!")
```

The application command also uses [discord.Interaction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#interaction) and not [Context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context) (ctx).

```
@bot.tree.command(name="setupBot", description="Enter role needed for access")
async def setupBot(interaction: discord.Interaction, role: discord.Role):

    await interaction.response.send_message("Setting up category and channels!")
```